# Is it possible to enable remoting for powershell only from few machines

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I want to execute commands on windows machine A from a remote windows machine B. For this I have to enable remoting on machine A using the command `Enable-PSRemoting`. In machine A,I wish to accept remote commands only from machine B. Is it possible to achieve this?

For example in machine B :

```
winrm set winrm/config/client ‘@{TrustedHosts="machineA"}
```

This would add machine A to the trusted hosts of machine B. Now machine B can remotely execute powershell commands on machine A.

So is there any command with Enable-PsRemoting through which we can configure the machines which can have access to the host.

Comment: I've not tried it but a simple search turns up the ports that PS remoting uses (5985, 5986) so I'd have thought a decent firewall rule could be set up.

Comment: Thanks.I wanted to check if that is possible with some powershell commands itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the Windows Firewall using Active Directory Group Policy to restrict which computers can access TCP port 5985. That would probably be the most effective way to achieve your goal. The Windows Remote Management (WinRM) service does not have any built-in method, that I'm aware of, to restrict which IP addresses can/can't connect to it. That would typically be the function of a software or hardware firewall.